# Error rendering react component (object instead of string)

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, object, jsx

I have a problem rendering a component with react. I'm trying to code a wizard, however I get the following error when rendering Mstep1.

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a here`class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You here`likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

To better explain, here is some code:

-- wizard.js --

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Mstep1, Mstep2 } from './Steps'
import { states } from './States'
import { StateMachine } from './StateMachine.js';

class Wizard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentState: states.MSTEP1,
            formSaves: [],

        }

        this.saveForm =this.saveForm.bind(this);
        this.nextStep = this.nextStep.bind(this);
        this.backStep = this.backStep.bind(this);
        this.stateMachine = new StateMachine();
    }

    saveForm(formSave) {
        let formSaves = this.state.formSaves.concat();
        formSaves.push(formSave);
        this.setState({
            formSaves: formSaves
        });
    }

    nextStep(desiredState) {
        let currentState = this.state.currentState;
        let nextState = this.stateMachine.transitionTo(currentState, desiredState);
        this.setState({
            currentState: nextState
        });
    }

    backStep(desiredState) {
        let currentState = this.state.currentState;
        this.setState({
            currentState: this.stateMachine.transitionFrom(currentState, desiredState)
        });
    }

    //Switch Case Methode um den CurrentStep zu bestimmen
    currentStep() {
        console.log(this.state.currentState);
        // console.log(typeof this.state.currentState);
        switch (this.state.currentState) {
            case states.MSTEP1:
            console.log(typeof states.MSTEP1);
                return <Mstep1
                    saveForm={this.save}
                    back={this.backStep}
                    next={this.nextStep}
                />;
                break;
            case states.MSTEP2:
                return(<Mstep2
                />);                     

            default:
                break;
        }


    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                {this.currentStep()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Wizard;
```

---

--Steps.js---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { states } from './States.js';


import TextArea from './Select';
import SingleInput from './SingleInput';

// import Select from './Select';



export class Mstep1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {    
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modultitel: '',
            startdate: '',
            enddate: '',
            modulkuerzel: '',
            modulDescription: ''
        };

        //Bindings 

        this.handleModultitel = this.handleModultitel.bind(this);
        this.handleStartdate = this.handleStartdate.bind(this);
        this.handleEnddate = this.handleEnddate.bind(this);
        this.handleModulkuerzel = this.handleModulkuerzel.bind(this);
        this.handlemodulDescriptionChange = this.handlemodulDescriptionChange.bind(this);
        this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
    }
    handleModultitel(e) {
        this.setState({ modultitel: e.target.value }, () => console.log('modultitel:', this.state.modultitel));
    }

    handleStartdate(e) {
        this.setState({ startdate: e.target.value }, () => console.log('startdate:', this.state.startdate));
    }

    handleEnddate(e) {
        this.setState({ enddate: e.target.value }, () => console.log('enddate:', this.state.enddate));
    }

    handleModulkuerzel(e) {
        this.setState({ modulkuerzel: e.target.value }, () => console.log('modulkuerzel', this.state.modulkuerzel));
    }

    handlemodulDescriptionChange(e) {
        // const textArray = e.target.value.split('').filter(x => x !== 'e');
        // console.log('string split into array of letters',textArray);
        // const filteredText = textArray.join('');
        // this.setState({ modulDescription: filteredText }, () => console.log('modulDescription', this.state.modulDescription));
        this.setState({ modulDescription: e.target.value }, () => console.log('modulDescription', this.state.modulDescription));
    }

    handleClearForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            modultitel: '',
            startdate: '',
            enddate: '',
            modulkuerzel: '',
            modulDescription: ''
        });
    }

    validate(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

       this.props.saveForm({
            modultitel: '',
            startdate: '',
            enddate: '',
            modulkuerzel: '',
            modulDescription: '',
        });
        this.props.next(this.props.nextState);


        this.handleClearForm(e);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <h5>Modul anlegen (Schritt 1 von x)</h5>
                <SingleInput
                    inputType={'text'}
                    title={'Modultitel: '}
                    name={'name'}
                    controlFunc={this.handleModultitel}
                    content={this.state.modultitel}
                    placeholder={'Modultitel'} />
                <SingleInput
                    inputType={'text'}
                    title={'Gültig ab: '}
                    name={'Startdate'}
                    controlFunc={this.handleStartdate}
                    content={this.state.startdate}
                    placeholder={'Startdatum'} />
                <SingleInput
                    inputType={'text'}
                    title={'Gültig bis: '}
                    name={'Enddate'}
                    controlFunc={this.handleEnddate}
                    content={this.state.enddate}
                    placeholder={'Enddatum'} />
                <SingleInput
                    inputType={'text'}
                    title={'Modulkürzel'}
                    name={'Modulkürzel'}
                    controlFunc={this.handleModulkuerzel}
                    content={this.state.modulkuerzel}
                    placeholder={'Modulkützel'} />
                <TextArea
                    title={'Kurzbeschreibung'}
                    rows={5}
                    name={'Kurzbeschreibung'}
                    resize={false}
                    content={this.state.modulDescription}
                    controlFunc={this.handlemodulDescriptionChange}
                    placeholder={'Kurzbeschreibung zu Modulen'} />
                <button
                    onClick={this.validate}>Weiter</button>
                <button
                    onClick={this.handleClearForm}>Clear form</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}// Ende Class Mstep1


export class Mstep2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modulThema: '',
            themaDescription: ''
        };
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleThemaDescription = this.handleThemaDescription.bind(this);
        this.back = this.back.bind(this);
    }

    handleModulthema(e) {
        this.setState({ modulThema: e.target.value }, () => console.log('thema: ', this.state.modulThema));
    }

    handleThemaDescription(e) {
        this.setState({ themaDescription: e.target.value }, () => console.log('tDescription', this.state.themaDescription))
    }

    back(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.back(states.MSTEP1);
    }


    validate(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.saveForm({
            modulThema: '',
            themaDescription: ''
        });
        this.props.next(this.props.nextState);

        this.handleClearForm(e);
    }



    render() {

        return (
            <form>
                <h5>Modul anlegen (Schritt 2 von x)</h5>
                <SingleInput
                    inputType={'text'}
                    title={'Neues Thema'}
                    name={'modulname'}
                    controlFunc={this.handleModulThema}
                    content={this.modulThema}
                    placeholder={'Modulthema'} />
                <TextArea
                    title={'Beschreibung (Inhalte des Thmas)'}
                    rows={5}
                    name={'Thema-Beschreibung'}
                    resize={10}
                    controlFunc={this.handleThemaDescription}
                    content={this.state.themaDescription}
                    placeholder={''} />
                <button
                    onClick={this.validate}>Weiter</button>
                    <button
                    onClick={this.back}>zurück</button>
                <button
                    onClick={this.handleClearForm}>Clear form</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Can you show States file?

Comment: Her is the Code:
import keyMirror from 'keymirror';

export const states = keyMirror({
    MSTEP1: true,
    MSTEP2: true,
});

Comment: import TextArea from './Select'; looks very suspicious - isn't the file name wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to split `Mstep1` and `Mstep2` into two different files and then you can `export default class Mstep1` for example and import with `import Mstep1 from 'Steps/Mstep1'`. It's a good practice in React that you stick to one component per file. Refer to [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/organize-large-react-application/) as a good reference to organize your `react` applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `export const class Mstep1` and `export const Mstep2`. So that you can import it like you already have.